# EmailValidator GetInstance Local?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Sorry, if this question is asked somewhere befor. I searched but didn't find an answer.

I've got a question about the Apache `EmailValidator`. I want to use this class to validate emails in my form, but I do not understand the difference between the methods:

```
static EmailValidator   getInstance()

static EmailValidator   getInstance(boolean allowLocal)
```

Here the Documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/index.html

I'am not sure but what means, `allowLocal`?

The documentation says:

> Should local addresses be considered valid?

But what are local addresses?

Comment: A local address might be something like `admin@localhost` etc.

Comment: @Thomas : OP is apparently looking for a definition of a *local address*.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, found that one about local adress: Returns true if the specified String parses as a valid domain name with a recognized top-level domain. The parsing is case-sensitive.

If I got it right, it checks for example .com is an correct ending

Comment: Hmm, I'd not consider a top-level domain such as `.com` or `.de` etc. a local domain. :) - According to the source `abc@xyz.com` would be a valid non-local email address while `abc@localhost` would be a local one and only be considered valid if `allowLocal` is true.

Comment: ok i definitly checked out while I used the Class, 
the local adress stands for .com .org. .de ...etc. Means that it checks the ending of the adress.

Example... max@info.com is validated true, while max@info.xx is false

Answer (score 1):

Addresses ending with `.localhost` or `.localdomain`. For example, `admin@server1.localhost` or `dave@mailserver.acme.localdomain`. From `org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.java`:

```
// WARNING: this array MUST be sorted, otherwise it cannot be searched reliably using binary search
private static final String[] LOCAL_TLDS = new String[] {
   "localdomain",         // Also widely used as localhost.localdomain
   "localhost",           // RFC2606 defined
};
```